# with docker-compose my app container cannot see the mongodb container

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose

Here is my docker compose file:

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  test:
    image: test
    networks:
      - mongo_net
    ports:
      - 4000:80
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    links:
      - mongodb

  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    networks:
      - mongo_net
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - local_data:/data/db

volumes:
  local_data:

networks:
  mongo_net:
    driver: bridge
```

The 'test' image cannot find the 'mongodb' instance.
My assumption is that the 'links' section would connect the two, but it is not happening.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

for your compose file try just using depends_on. links is deprecated and maybe thats why you are currently getting issues since this is a V3 compose file.

Comment: oh darn, umm can you post your docker compose up output

Comment: Creating network "backend_default" with the default driver
Creating mongodb ... done
Creating test ... done

Comment: I think the process works properly, but the name 'mongodb' is just not visible from the container

Comment: your compose file looks fine, what you can try is making sure everything is shut down and restarting by doing.      docker-compose stop
docker-compose rm

Then try with docker-compose up -d

Comment: I killed all instances, restarted them, etc; but them I realized that other docker setups I have did not work anymore! A reboot solved it! I'm on mac, so maybe there are still some issues with docker mac. Anyhow, thanks for the help